# How to determine if text is selected in Microsoft Word VBA..?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word VBA, I would like to know the proper method to determine if text is selected. I may have the answer (shown below), but I want to ask if it's correct.

This is confusing, because most of the properties show no difference between *nothing* selected and *one character* selected.

An obvious possibility is `If Selection.End - Selection.Start > 0`, but this seems unnecessary. Is there not a specific property that is `True` or `False`..?

I see the property `Selection.Type`, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdselectiontype) is very thin and unhelpful. It does not explain any details, such as the definitions of Normal, Inline, Block or any of the others. And searching Google for these answers was not helpful.

Through experimentation, I may have found the answer:

- `Selection.Type=wdSelectionIP` seems to be when nothing is selected.
- `Selection.Type=wdSelectionNormal` seems to be when any text is selected.

Is this the correct & reliable way to do it..?

Comment: Yes, `Selection.Type` is how to determine it.

Comment: Ok. What is the purpose of `wdNoSelection`..? I have not been able to determine when this type becomes active.

Comment: I can't recall that I've ever been able to trigger that one, either. There's this discussion that indicates it *can* happen: http://computer-programming-forum.com/1-vba/25604fea56504b16.htm The discussion leads one to think it can happen when Word is in a "unstable state" - it can't "know" where the selection is, at the particular moment the line executes.

Comment: Ahhh. My experiences mirror those of the participants in that discussion. I tried a variety of similar ways to trigger, got it only once, and could not repeat it.

Comment: I "know" Steve Hudson (never met him, personally, but lots of contact years ago, on the newsgroups) and if he couldn't reproduced it reliably, then it can't be done reliably :-) A genius...

Comment: Sounds like he has one of those flashy swords like He-Man, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Compare `Selection.Type` against `wdSelectionIP`. I have provided the code sample as below:

.

'Simple check if text is selected:

```
If (Selection.Type <> wdSelectionIP) Then
   Debug.Print  "You have selected: " & Selection.Text
Else
   Debug.Print  "No text is selected."
End If
```

.

'Graceful exit with message - if no selection found:

```
If Not (Selection.Type <> wdSelectionIP) Then
   MsgBox "Text not selected." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please select text before proceeding", vbOKOnly & vbExclamation, "Selection not found"
   Exit Sub
End If
```

.

This was also righty suggested by @Cindy Meister.

**Reference**: [Microsoft Documentation (Selection.Type property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.type).